# Using array_search() to return key of first element that does not match the search string

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, backend

If there is a way by which `array_search()` would return key of its first conflict like if I run

```
$key = array_search(40489, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));
```

on

```
Array
(

    (1) => Array
        (
            (uid) => '5465',
            (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof100'
        ),

    (2) => Array
        (
            (uid) => '40489',
            (name) => 'Michael',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof40489'
        )
);
```

it would ideally return

> 2

but I want it to return

> 1

i.e the first element that did not have the 'uid' = 40489
&

If its not possible with `array_search()` is there any other way to do it with loops? I tried `array_filter()` but can't get it to work.

Comment: `array_search` searches for an element in array. It doesn't do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in `array_search` description:

> Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
>
> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

So, you cannot use `array_search` to search something that not equals what you need. Instead write you own function, for example:

```
$array = [];    // your array
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['uid'] != '40489') {
        echo 'Key: ', $key;
        // use `break` to stop iterating over 
        // array as you already found what you need
        break;
    }
}
```